# Retrieving dependencies with empty type

Tags: ivy

I'm trying to figure out how to omit the [type] part in an Ivy retrieve pattern for artifacts that don't have type declared. I use the following ant statement:

`<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact](-[type]).[ext]" conf="compile" />`

Despite the parentheses, Ivy produces files like

- junit-jar.jar
- junit-javadoc.jar
- junit-source.jar

The latter two ones are as expected but the first one should be "junit.jar" instead.

The result is the same as when I omit the parentheses.

**Edit:**

What I'm doing up to now to work around the problem: I have multiple retrieve statements in the build.xml:

`<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[type].[ext]" type="source" />`
`<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" type="jar" />`

(The "conf" attribute in the original post is not related to this topic.)

But that looks rather silly when there's the feature of optional tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type defaults to jar, it can't be ommited. See [Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact.html)
So this (-[type]) does not have an affect.

Perhaps you could do something like this in the build.xml (if you control the ivy.xml).

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" conf="compile" />
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact](-[type]).[ext]" conf="extras" />
```

You'd have to publish the jar in the compile config and  the other jars in the extra config.

Or just name the other ones junit-javadoc and junit-source in the ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="junit"
        module="jnuit"
        revision="4.8.2"
        status="release"
        publication="20110531150115"
        default="true"
    />
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
      <artifact name="junit"      type="jar" />
      <artifact name="junit-sources"      type="jar" />
      <artifact name="junit-javadoc"      type="jar" />
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: That looks more like the build.xml. I have these two lines there at the moment. But it feels a little awkward.

Comment: @Wolfgang I meant, that you'd have to alter the ivy.xml to use the following lines in the build.xml. I updated the second suggestion a bit, to make it more clear.

Comment: Hm, I don't think I want to change / re-define the ivy.xml of every dependency I have. Going with two ivy:retrieve already works without changing the ivy.xml. I use the attribuets type="jar" / "source" in the retrieve tags.

Comment: There seems to be no other ivy-solution, because of the DEFAULT-Value for the type attribute. There is always a value (jar) for type, so that the optional token will be evaluated for every artifact.